# Deserialize timestamp from postgres into google.protobuf.Timestamp with sqlx

Tags: postgresql, go, protocol-buffers, sqlx

I have a postgres table with a `creation_time` field defined like this:

```sql
creation_time timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
```

And I have a protobuf message defined like this:

```protobuf
message Thing {
    //...Other fields here
    google.protobuf.Timestamp creation_time = 1;
}
```

After generating my go struct with protoc, I end up with a Go struct like this:

```golang
type Thing struct {
    CreationTime *timestamppb.Timestamp `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=creation_time,json=creationTime,proto3" json:"creation_time,omitempty"`
}
```

I use sqlx to read and write into a postgres database. I want to read a database record and deserialize it into a `Thing` struct. The deserialization works for all the "trivial" fields (ints, strings) but the timestamp is giving me trouble. As you can see above, the `CreationTime` field ends up being of type `*timestamppb.Timestamp` and sqlx doesn't know how to handle this type (it doesn't have the `Value` and `Scan` methods for this type).

I would like to know how people handle this situation, I believe it must happen all the time as it's so fundamental.

I am aware that I could use the protobuf struct only for the communication with my API and use a normal go struct for internal business logic, and write some adapters to handle the conversion. I don't want to go this way, I would like to use the proto struct everywhere. I am also aware that I could use lots of `sqlx.Scan` to specifically handle the timestamps. But I'd have to do that in multiple places in my code and I don't like this idea.

I was thinking about implementing my own timestamp proto type (might be just a wrapper around google's timestamp type), just so I can implement the scanner and valuer interface.

How do you people normally do?

Answer (score 0):

Here are common strategies people use to handle this situation:

1. Implement the Scanner and Valuer interface for your protobuf
   Timestamp. This is essentially what you've mentioned — creating a
   wrapper around the timestamppb.Timestamp or your custom timestamp
   type. This way, you can directly control how to read from and write
   to the database. The wrapper would convert between the database's
   timestamp format and the protobuf timestamp.
2. Introduce a middleware layer or use repository pattern where the
   conversion logic is centralized. In this approach, the repository
   functions are responsible for reading from the database into a
   Go-native structure (like time.Time for timestamps) and then
   converting it to the necessary protobuf type. This keeps the
   conversion logic in one place and avoids scattering sqlx.Scan calls
   throughout your code.
3. Utilize nullable time types that are compatible with sqlx. Libraries
   like github.com/guregu/null or github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/types provide
   NullTime types which can be scanned directly from SQL and can be
   checked for nullability. You would then convert this into your
   protobuf timestamp type as needed.
4. Some frameworks or libraries allow you to define hooks or custom
   types that integrate with the ORM's lifecycle. This means you can
   intercept a value after it's read from the database but before it's
   assigned to the struct field, or vice versa. You can use this hook
   to convert the timestamp.
5. Create functions specifically for serializing and deserializing
   between your database models and your protobuf models. This is more
   manual but allows for explicit control over how each field is
   handled.

I prefer the third variant. Here is the snippets with how it may look like:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/guregu/null"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    // other necessary imports
)

type Thing struct {
    // ... other fields here
    CreationTime null.Time `db:"creation_time"`
}
```

read from DB:

```
// Assuming db is *sqlx.DB and properly initialized
var thing Thing
err := db.Get(&thing, "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id=$1", yourID)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Now, thing.CreationTime will be of type null.Time
// You can check if it's valid and then get the time value
if thing.CreationTime.Valid {
    // Use thing.CreationTime.Time which is a time.Time
}
```

convert back to TimeStamp:

```
import (
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb"
    // other necessary imports
)

// ... assuming you have a thing instance from the database

if thing.CreationTime.Valid {
    protoTimestamp := timestamppb.New(thing.CreationTime.Time)
    // Now, protoTimestamp is a *timestamppb.Timestamp that you can set in your protobuf message
    // Use protoTimestamp as needed
}
```

By using null.Time, you allow sqlx to automatically handle the nullable aspect of the timestamp directly from SQL queries. This approach keeps your database code cleaner and makes it easier to deal with the possibility of null timestamps. The conversion back to the protobuf timestamp when you need to work with the protobuf message is straightforward